# Select a substring of characters from the end of a character string in R

Tags: r, string

I have a vector of character strings

```
vec <- c("1ZQOYNBAA55", "2JSNHGKLRBB66", "3HVXCC77", "4LDD88", "5CIFMTLYXEE99")

> vec
[1] "1ZQOYNBAA55"   "2JSNHGKLRBB66" "3HVXCC77"      "4LDD88"        "5CIFMTLYXEE99"
```

...and I would like to get the last 3 characters from each string. To get the first 3 characters, I can use `substr()`

```
substr(vec,1,3)
```

I would have thought something like `substr()` with a "fromLast" argument might exist

```
vec_ends <- substr(vec,1,3, fromLast = TRUE)
```

With an expected output

```
> vec_ends
[1] "A55" "B66" "C77" "D88" "E99"
```

But `substr()` only works one way. In my dataset the string lengths are variable so no reference to absolute character numbers or string lengths can be made, and there are no consistent separators of delimiting characters for a string split. Does anyone know of an easy way to do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that doesn't use regex (which often but not always means it's faster).

```r
get_last_n_chars  <- function(vec, n = 3) {
    
    substr(vec, nchar(vec)-(n-1), nchar(vec))

}

get_last_n_chars(vec)
# [1]  "A55" "B66" "C77" "D88" "E99"
```

#### Benchmarking - just for fun

Often (usually?!) performance is irrelevant and you should use whatever code is clearest.

However, I was interested, and it does appear in this case that avoiding regex is faster. However the really big win is not using `sapply(strsplit())` method - I actually had to cut off the final point from the plot because it broke the scale.

```r
input_vec  <- c("1ZQOYNBAA55", "2JSNHGKLRBB66", "3HVXCC77", "4LDD88", "5CIFMTLYXEE99")

num_iterations  <- c(10, 1e3, 1e4)
results <- bench::press(
    rows = num_iterations,
    {
        vec  <- rep(input_vec, rows)
        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 100,
            sub = {
                sub(".*(.{3})$", "\\1", vec)
            },
            gsub = {
                gsub(".*(.{3})$", "\\1", vec)
            },
            strsplit = {
                sapply(strsplit(vec, split=""),  function(x) paste(tail(x, 3), collapse = ""))
            },
            get_last_n_chars_fun = {
                get_last_n_chars(vec)
            },
            stringi = {
                out <- stringi::stri_reverse(vec)
                out <- substr(out,1,3)
                out <- stringi::stri_reverse(out)
                out
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Plot of results:

[image]

Output of `autoplot(results) + theme_bw()`:

[image]

Comment: I was just about to post something like this. Notice that yours has 1 too many chars. try `nchar(vec)-n-1`

Comment: @AndS. yes I just spotted and fixed this! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `sub()` approach:

```
vec_ends <- sub(".*(.{3})$", "\\1", vec)
vec_ends

[1] "A55" "B66" "C77" "D88" "E99"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> gsub(".*(.{3})$", "\\1", vec)
[1] "A55" "B66" "C77" "D88" "E99"
```

Here´s an alternative without using regex:

```
> sapply(strsplit(vec, split=""),  function(x) paste(tail(x, 3), collapse = ""))
[1] "A55" "B66" "C77" "D88" "E99"
```

Comment: There is no point in calling `gsub()`, as the pattern covers the entire string and will only be appled once.  Instead, use plain `sub()`.

Answer (score 1):

I also found this package `stringi`, and with double use of `stri_reverse()` it can be done.

```
library(stringi)

out <- stri_reverse(vec)
out <- substr(out,1,3)
out <- stri_reverse(out)
```