# Faster version of strsplit in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a data such as sequence of string where text and number type alternate: e.g. VID22CAS05, TEL21XSE12 and I need to check the length of items after parsing, e.g. VID22CAS05 -> VID 22 CAS 05 => length of 4.

```
data <- c("VID22CAS05", "TEL21XSE12")

string_lengths<-purrr::map(data, function(x){
    x_sep <- trimws(x = gsub("(\\d+|[A-Za-z]+)", "\\1 ", x), which = "both")
    length <- strsplit(x_sep, " ")[[1]]
})
```

This works fine but the problem is that this is very slow for huge dataset.

Is there any way, how to speed this up?

Comment: Setting fixed = TRUE should make it substantially faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already tried with fixed = TRUE but there is not so much difference.

Comment: `strsplit()` is very slow compared to solutions which do not create lots of new objects in memory. See some benchmarking in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74196599/12545041) answer.  As the vectors are just an intermediate variable that you're throwing away, any approach that does not use `strsplit()` should be significantly faster.

Comment: While I do agree with @SamR in general, in this particular case `strsplit()` is doing a surprisingly good job in comparison to the solution with `gregexpr()`, cf. my answer below. Indeed, there are comparable faster solutions at hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this do?

```r
lengths(gregexpr('\\d+|[a-zA-Z]+', data))
# [1] 4 4
```

Answer (score 1):

I have put this together, included a solution based on `strsplit` and added another one using package `stringi`. Then I evaluate the performance using random data and `microbenchmark`, getting the following result.

```r
require(stringi)
require(microbenchmark)

set.seed(42)
n <- 100000L

data <- stri_rand_shuffle(stri_paste(
    stri_rand_strings(n, sample(5:11, 5, replace = TRUE), "[A-Z]"),
    stri_rand_strings(n, sample(5:11, 5, replace = TRUE), "[0-9]")))

microbenchmark(lengths(gregexpr("\\d+|[a-zA-Z]+", data)),
               unlist(lapply(strsplit(data, "\\d+|[A-Z]+"), length)),
               nchar(gsub("\\d+|[A-Z]+", "_", data)),
               stri_count_regex(data, "\\d+|[a-zA-Z]+"),
               times = 10L)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>                                                     expr      min       lq
#>              lengths(gregexpr("\\\\d+|[a-zA-Z]+", data)) 509.1273 562.6491
#>  unlist(lapply(strsplit(data, "\\\\d+|[A-Z]+"), length)) 499.3535 505.2245
#>                  nchar(gsub("\\\\d+|[A-Z]+", "_", data)) 248.5850 249.4832
#>               stri_count_regex(data, "\\\\d+|[a-zA-Z]+")  84.0736  84.7188
#>       mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  604.38020 607.2948 633.2371 677.1071    10
#>  516.07114 513.0919 515.4636 557.8389    10
#>  250.19865 250.0769 250.9425 252.5554    10
#>   85.40322  85.1071  86.5041  87.0498    10
```

So, using `stri_count_regex` from the `stringi` package seems to be the fastest. Please note that I adjusted the very nice and compact answer from @akrun so that it matches the results from the other approaches.

<sup>Created on 2022-12-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

How about rethinking the problem, *when we know text and number type alternate*? Counting the occurrence of digits only and inferring the character count could speed things up further.

```r
library(stringr)

str_count(data, "\\d+")*2
```

Output:

```r
[1] 4 4 6
```

Data:

```r
data<- c("VID22CAS05", "TEL21XSE12", "TEL21XSE12XSE12")
```

Comment: What about e.g. 'A1B'?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If text and number types do not alternate in the way OP is describing, it won't work. If it does, it should be a fast alternative to several regex matches.

Answer (score -1):

A `base R` option with `gsub` and `nchar`

```
nchar(gsub("\\D+", "", data))
[1] 4 4
```